# perform httprequest in batch file

Tags: command-line, cmd, httprequest, batch-file

I have created a batch file (.cmd) to perform numerous tasks when installing a web application One of the tasks I want to perform is start the web application by performing a http request to the sites homepage. How can I do this? I would prefer not to have to use any external libraries or the like if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), which is a command-line utility that can be used to retrieve webpages.