# Open a URL without using a browser from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to open a particular URL without directly opening the browser using only a batch file. I know I can use something like:

```
START www.google.com
```

But I want to open a URL without using a browser. Is this possible?

The reason is that I have to open like 30 URLs, and I don't want the user to have like 30 tabs opened on his/her pc.

Comment: You can use wget or curl, see http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget

Comment: What is your real intention? "Open a URL", to me, means opening a browser page to allow user to browse it.

Comment: If you don't use a browser then you will not see the `www.google.com` page.  Are you doing something else, like downloading files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perform httprequest in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284866/perform-httprequest-in-batch-file)

Comment: What do you mean by "open a URL without using a browser"? What should happen? For example, should the corresponding HTML content be saved to disk? If yes, what about other content (images, CSS, JavaScript, etc.)?

Comment: Use a dedicated Chromium instance.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If all you want is to request the URL and if it needs to be done from batch file, without anything outside of the OS, this can help you:

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem The batch file will delegate all the work to the script engine
    if not "%~1"=="" (
        wscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" %1
    )

    rem End of batch file area. Ensure the batch file ends execution
    rem before reaching the JavaScript zone
    exit /b

@end


// **** JavaScript zone *****************************************************
// Instantiate the needed component to make URL queries
var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');

// Retrieve the URL parameter
var url = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

// Make the request

http.open("GET", url, false);
http.send();

// All done. Exit
WScript.Quit(0);
```

It is just a hybrid batch/JavaScript file and is saved as `callurl.cmd` and called as `callurl "http://www.google.es"`. It will do what you ask for. No error check, no post, just a skeleton.

If it is possible to use something outside of the OS, `wget` or `curl` are available as Windows executables and are the best options available.

If you are limited by some kind of security policy, you can get the [Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17275). It includes `tinyget` and `wfetch` tools that can do what you need.

Comment: Works like a charm for my use, much appreciated MC ND!

Comment: For one wondering, how does this work, %~dpnx0 specifies the full path to the current file being run, so we're calling into wscript to run this as a JavaScript file via ( //E:engine ), where the chosen engine is JavaScript, and %1 is the first parameter of the batch file, which this is passing forward.  Interesting solution.

Comment: Where in this script do you actually define the URL you want to request?

Comment: @square_eyes, as indicated, it is passed as argument to the batch file. You can replace all the references to `%1` (the first argument to the batch file) with the url you want (don't forget quotes if it contains special characters)

Comment: Where in the script I can set the URL that I want to request ?

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues, If you don't want to use the indicated behaviour (the url is given as the argument when calling the batch file) replace in the code `%1` (the first argument to the batch file) with  the url you want to use (better quote it to avoid problems with special characters).

Comment: @MCND Thanks for the answer. So, I have changed the %1 to "http://www.google.com" ( just to test ), It gives me an Access denied when I execute the cmd file.

Comment: @EdsonRodrigues, try changing the instantiated component. Replace `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0` with `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0`

Comment: @MCND Great solution thanks. I have one question though, I am using this to kill a selenium server, however sometimes selenium might die on its own and i want to schedule this task, now if the server is dead the URL used to kill it can't be accessed so i get an error box appear "The system cannot locate the resource specified" that makes perfect sense since the server is inactive, but how can i dismiss that message box or suppress it? I've had a quick look and couldn't see anything but i might be searching for the wrong thing. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sirk, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590203/2861476). You will not need the quote handling, but the code includes the error handling

Answer (score 17):

You can use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), see *[How to download files from command line in Windows like wget or curl](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-or-curl)*.

You will then do e.g.:

```
wget www.google.com
```

Comment: Somehow the link in your post gets automatically redirected to - http://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing

Comment: @RBT someone edited that post: http://superuser.com/posts/25538/revisions

Comment: wget and curl are not included in stock/vanilla windows, so not always a great option if you're trying to share a quick/easy script with others... step 1: download these other tools and configure them (seems like a big pain for an "easy" script solution).

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [HH command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489254/hh-exe-can-show-html-jpeg-files/46495852#46495852) to open any website.

```
hh <http://url>
```

For example,

```
hh http://shuvankar.com
```

Though it will not open the website in the browser, but this will open the website in an HTML help window.

Comment: works great to just hit a website to log an IP or kick off a script.
*Note* that (as OP said, ) User does not see the website, and has to close the awkward help popup saying "Page not found".

Comment: @Shuvankar Sarkar, after call this, how do I close the popup HTML help window in script?

Comment: Is there a way to invoke this in background without the GUI

Answer (score 13):

Not sure whether you have already gotten your owner solution. I have been using the following powshell command to achieve it:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://your_url"
```

Comment: Wow this worked like a charm. So simple, and just does the job.

Comment: Try that with https with self-signed cert using Task Scheduler and simplicity dies.

Answer (score 5):

Try [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat). It uses a winhttp request object that should be faster than
Msxml2.XMLHTTP as there isn't any DOM parsing of the response. It is capable to do requests with body and all HTTP methods.

```
call winhttpjs.bat  http://somelink.com/something.html -saveTo c:\something.html
```

Comment: how to use in linux

Comment: Winhttpjs.bat is one of my favorites!

@Gem winhttpjs.bat is a tool designed for batch, which is a Windows-Only coding language. On linux there is bash on which there are built-in tools such as `curl` or `wget` to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
start /min iexplore http://www.google.com
```

With the use of [/min](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html), it will hit on the URL without opening in the browser.

Comment: This solution still launches a browser (but keeps the focus on the current app).

Answer (score -1):

The perfect solution with `curl`

```
curl www.google.com
```

Comment: Not stock vanilla included on windows, so rather useless

Answer (score -4):

You can try put in a shortcut to the site and tell the .bat file to open that.

```
start Google.HTML
exit
```

Comment: OP asks for a solution that does not open i a browser, and have already said that he knows the START command, and that he does not like the result