# Is it possible to display the HTML Code of a webpage in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, html

For my new program I want to echo the code of a webpage. I searched on google and Stack Overflow but didn´t found something like this. I do not want to use external programs like URL2FILE or something like this.

Comment: im not 100% sure this is possible on windows without something like python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL without using a browser from a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782734/open-a-url-without-using-a-browser-from-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is from a previous question that only needed to do the query to the server (linked in comments) with the "display" of the page source code added.

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Batch file will delegate all the work to the script engine 
    if not "%~1"=="" (
        cscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" %1
    )

    rem End of batch area. Ensure batch ends execution before reaching
    rem javascript zone
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************

    // Instantiate the needed component to make url queries
    var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');

    // Retrieve the url parameter
    var url = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

    // Make the request

    http.open("GET", url, false);
    http.send();

    // If we get a OK from server (status 200), echo data to console

    if (http.status === 200) WScript.StdOut.Write(http.responseText);

    // All done. Exit
    WScript.Quit(0);
```

It is just an hybrid batch/javascript file. Saved as `callurl.cmd` and called as `callurl "http://www.google.es"` it will do what you ask for. No error check appart from correct response, no post, just a skeleton.

Comment: It closes instatly when I start it with a second Batch file. (I am a noob at hybrid files)

Comment: @user3608791, there is no difference from a normal batch file. Does it run when directly called from command line?

Comment: Yes. But instantly disappears.

Comment: @user3608791, from command line you type `callurl.cmd "http://www.google.com"` and it disappears?

Comment: Yes it disappears instantly

Comment: @user3608791, there is nothing in the code to make it dissapear. The only thing that can happen is that you do not get a HTTP 200 code and the script directly exits. As indicated, there is no error check, just an skeleton. Add code to know what the response is.

Comment: Ok Thank you. But I dont know Javascript/Hybrid files.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the source code of a webpage in the console line?

In Linux you can use `GET google.com`.

Comment: Yea. But in A bacth Console Line. In Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below *display in the screen* the HTML Code of the webpage given in the parameter, so I think it is a solution to this topic.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
rem Start explorer with the web page and wait for it to initialize
start "" Explorer.exe %1
timeout /T 5 > NUL
rem Send to Explorer: Alt-V (View tab)...
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%%V"
timeout /T 1 > NUL
rem ... followed by S (Source)
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "S"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Use previous program this way:

```
test.bat http://www.google.com
```

For further details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file/17050135#17050135).

Comment: It only opens google.com in chrome, not the HTML Code in the Batch file.

Comment: The program send the keys used in IExplorer to show the source HTML code: Alt-V and S. You may change those keys by the ones used in Chrome...