# Fetch HTML and save it to a file with Windows command line

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to save the html source of a fetched web page into a file and I want to do this using only the CMD prompt on Windows.

I could do this with wget, but that requires using the wget program.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a Batch-JScript hybrid script to do that in a very easy way. The JScript support is installed with all Windows versions from XP on.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%~1" > "%~N1.html"
goto :EOF

@end

var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');
http.open("GET", WScript.Arguments.Item(0), false);
http.send();

if (http.status == 200) {
   WScript.StdOut.Write(http.responseText);
} else {
   WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Error: Status "+http.status+" returned on download.");
}
```

Save previous code in a .BAT file, for example: GetHtmlCode.bat, and execute it with the web address in the first parameter:

```
GetHtmlCode.bat "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975698/get-code-html-to-a-file-whit-cmd"
```

I borrowed previous code from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502011/is-it-possible-to-display-the-html-code-of-a-webpage-in-a-batch-file) and just did a couple small changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure that there is no CMD internal command to achieve this. This means looking to other utilities installed with the OS. Several options there.

Have a look at this Stack Overfow question: [Windows batch file file download from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url)

You could possibly use BITS or VBSCRIPT. Both built into XP.

Find more BITS examples [here](http://www.out-web.net/?p=151).

If you cant use something built in, another possibility is to use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

It's been a while since I used AutoIt, but it is quite powerful. You can write your script, compile to a standalone .EXE and then deploy. No runtime is required.

It is also possible to include additional files in the compiled EXE. So you could deploy WGET as part of the package.

Answer (score 1):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) it's as simple as:

```
xidel.exe -s "<url>" -e "$raw" > output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use powershell?

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://example.com/page')) | out-file -FilePath page.html
```

Comment: it's a good anwser but doesn't work with xp. Thanks. (maybe this is not possible just with CMD)

Comment: right, you need to run it in powershell, which I don't remember if that's possible to get on XP or not

Comment: Does not work:PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://google.de')) | out
-file -FilePath O:\tmp\page.html
iex : At line:1 char:1234
+ ... ript>(function(){window.google={kEI:'yr3pWcz_NoT76AT27KGgAg',kEXPI:'18167,135282 ...
+                    ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:1 char:1279
+ ... NoT76AT27KGgAg',kEXPI:'18167,1352821,1353383,1354277,1354402,1354915,1355087,135 ...
+                    ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:2623
+ ... le.kHL='de';})();(function(){google.lc=[];g...

Comment: @DennyWeinberg seems like that is an issue with ie attempting to execute the scripts in the html rather than this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file from internet using windows Power Shell using the following

```
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

Comment: it's a good anwser but doesn't work with xp. Thanks. (maybe this is not possible just with CMD)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. for windows XP try the following tool http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 0):

As of the Windows 10 May 2019 update (1903) you can use curl to get the html from the site and store it as a HTML file like this:

`curl <your link> -o <filename>.html`

Comment: Curl is not a CMD internal command and it may not be available in some Windows installations. Maybe you should clarify this.