# batch file getting output on browser instead of cmd line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cron

Below is my batchfile script. When i setup cronjob via Taskscheduler and run the bat file, cmd line opens with the below batchfile script. But at the same time below specified url is opens in browser and getting the output on browser.

```
cmd /k start "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" "http://localhost/server/php/ping1.php"
```

But I need output on the commandline instead of opening in browser.How can i achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

File should execute via cmd line only . But it is executing via browser.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of your question. Do you want the output of the `php` file in the console or the output of the `html` created when the command is run? can you give some examples of the expected output by editing your question? So show example of what the html output is as well as the content of the `.php`

Comment: File should execute via cmd line only . But it is executing via browser.

Comment: still unclear, what file? show the content of the php file as well as your expected output you require.

Comment: for example the file name is insert.php . when i run the file the insert query should execute and insert in the related table via cmd line. Not via browser. The file should not open/run/execute  via browser. It should execute via command line only

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23512143/2861476) is what you need.

Comment: What file?? The PHP file?

Comment: yes php file only

Comment: just the content of the php on command line? You need to help me help you. please edit the question and add the expected output and content of the PHP file.

Comment: or do you want the content of the php file to execute on command line? please show the content of the php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some 3rd party utility such as wget or curl. Then you can use

```
curl.exe -k --url https://localhost/server/php/ping1.php
```

Comment: This is what i exactly want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that your problem is with the Start command.

Either get rid of it completely:

```bat
cmd /k ""D:\xampp\php\php.exe" "http://localhost/server/php/ping1.php""
```

Or use it with it's correct structure *(title)*:

```bat
cmd /k "start "running php" "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" "http://localhost/server/php/ping1.php""
```