# How to open a link with CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

How can I open this [link](http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-DABAC3AA-C2A0C3AF-C2ABC3AF-C3AADABAC3A8C2AB-C3AAC2A0DABAC2ACC2A920-video_0a915c1da.html) using command line code?

I think I have a mistake with my code:

```
if %X% EQU 28 srart http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html
```

Comment: Using this "start http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html"   (use without Quotation mark)

Comment: [SuperUser Question](http://superuser.com/questions/719346/open-a-website-in-internet-explorer-from-command-line)

Comment: thank you Parth Akbari this link work with my browser but doesn't work with my batch-file ??

Comment: this might be help u [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782734/open-a-url-without-using-a-browser-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: is `srart` a typing error here, or is it in your actual code?

Comment: Are the `%` symbols required in the URL? You have to escape those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

> **Syntax**
>
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
>
> **Key**:
>
> - title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> - path        Starting directory.
> - command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> - parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
> - title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> - path        Starting directory.
> - command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> - parameters  The parameters passed to the command.

Things to note:

- `title` argument is **required**
- `command` should be quoted with <kbd>"</kbd> characters.

**"I think I have a mistake with my code:"**

```
if %X% EQU 28 srart http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html
```

There are three things I can see that might cause problems with the above code:

1. You have a spelling mistake, `srart` should be `start`,
2. You don't have a `title` parameter (which is **required**)
3. `command` is not quoted. Note that quotes are required if the command includes any of the following special characters `& \ < > ^ |` so it a good idea to always quoted the command.

Please try the following:

```
if %X% EQU 28 start "mytitle" "http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html"
```

Comment: A title is only required if there are quotes in the command. `start iexplore.exe` and `start "" "iexplore.exe" ` both function equally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
start browser.exe www.example.com
```

But. you need to set this to enviroment variables:

browser.exe C:\path\to\yourbrowser.exe
Search up a tutorial on how to setup enviromental variables based on your Windows
If you want to skip and use Internet Explorer, do this:

```
start iexplore.exe www.example.com
```

In another way you can also do this:

```
start C:\path\to\browser.exe www.example.com
```

But, if you want to use Chrome for example do this:

```
start C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe www.example.com
```

And if you want to use the same way for your code do this:

```
if %X% EQU 28 start iexplore.exe http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html
```

For example i want to use Chrome for this:

```
if %X% EQU 28 start C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application http://www.tele-live.com/mbc-max-en-direct-live-%DA%BA%C3%AA-%C2%A0%C3%AF-%C2%AB%C3%AF-%C3%AA%DA%BA%C3%A8%C2%AB-%C3%AA%C2%A0%DA%BA%C2%AC%C2%A9%20-video_0a915c1da.html
```

Bye..