# Go to the link every 10 minutes

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to go to a certain link every 10 minutes. I did a batch file to run an IE instance with path specified:

```
start /d iexplore.exe http://dbmsportal/generateXML.php
```

Task completes well, but the problem is Task Scheduler creates a new instances of iexplore each time.

I am new in a CMD commands could someone suggest me how to regularly proceed bat file within one instance. Maybe I have to kill the process each time?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have something in JavaScript that simply refreshes the page every 10 minutes?

Comment: @SomethingDark I don't have an access to the target link webpage's source. Also it might not be opened all time. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: You can try with the batch file in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590203/2861476).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive come up with scheduling another process that kills All iexplore processes each hour:

```
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

I know this is not a good solution, but I don't have time to learn VBS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBS script. Alter it to suit.

The LocationName is the title bar text (which is hidden in current versions of windows. I've thrown a msgbox in to display it. Delete the line when you find it.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Do 
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    For Each window in AllWindows
        msgbox window.locationname
        If window.locationname = "website1.com" then
            window.refresh2 3
        End If
    Next
    Wscript.sleep 5000
Loop
```

Comment: Don't put this in task scheduler. Some TS settings will prevent access. Press Winkey + R and type `shell:startup` and put this there. It always runs. As set it's 5 secs (or 5000 ms).

Comment: Your code works well, but I have to open the browser and keep the link opened, which is not acceptable in my case. Any ideas of how to do it as a background process?

Comment: Actually I don't need the browser content, it just a command to generate some XML, I would like to close this link after like couple of minutes.

Comment: Schedule it in TS then. I thought you wanted to look at it.

Comment: Thanks Noodles. Ive come up with scheduling another process that kills all iexplore processes each hour.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a hidden window and add this on a new line before the code you currently have:

```
:openLink
timeout /T 600 >nul
```

and after the line of code you currently have add this:

```
goto :openLink
```