# HH.EXE can show HTML/JPEG files

Tags: html-help

Apparently, one can view HTML and JPEG files (possibly others, didn't try), with HH.EXE, i.e. Microsoft's CHM file viewer.

Try "HH somefile.html". It was tested on Windows XP and Windows 10. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not documented public but it comes as little surprise.

HH.exe is the HTMLHelp executable and associated with *.CHM files. It's just a shell that uses the HTML Help API and is really just hosting a browser window. That is the reason why HTML, JPEG, GIF and animated GIF works. Microsoft Help MVP's always knew that but it's not really useful. Example:

```
PS D:\_temp> hh.exe -800 images\welcome_small_big-en.gif
```

HH.EXE is not single instance, if you open a CHM or another file three times using HH.EXE, then three help windows will appear.

Several client-side command line switches are available to help authors that are part of the HTML Help executable program (hh.exe) and therefore work when HTML Help Workshop is not set up.

For further Informationen see my site at [HTMLHelp command-line](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm).